# GloVe - Subscript out of bounds error in R

Tags: r, search, word-embedding, glove

I am attempting to write a feature that checks for each query what the maximum score is. The query is the search term, and the glove word vectors are trained using product descriptions. The code I use for training the word vectors and the feature itself (all.gloveterms) are listed below. 
I am receiving the error: Error in word_vectors[query, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds, after attempting to execute the command: all.gloveterms(query_product$search_term[2]), where the search term should return "angle bracket". I am having a hard time finding out how to fix this error, and was wondering if anyone can help.

```
#select product descriptions
descriptions <- product_descriptions[,2]
descriptions <- removePunctuation(descriptions)
descriptions <- tolower(descriptions)

it = itoken(descriptions, tolower, word_tokenizer, n_chunks = 10)

#find vocab from product descriptions
vocab = create_vocabulary(it)
dim(vocab)
vocab = prune_vocabulary(vocab, term_count_min = 10, doc_proportion_max = 0.8,doc_proportion_min = 0.001, vocab_term_max = 20000)
dim(vocab)
vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(vocab)

# create term co-occurrence matrix with window-size 5
tcm = create_tcm(it, vectorizer, skip_grams_window = 5L)

# train the word vectors
glove = GlobalVectors$new(rank = 50, x_max = 10)
wv_main = glove$fit_transform(tcm, n_iter = 50, convergence_tol = 0.01)
wv_context = glove$components
word_vectors = wv_main + t(wv_context)

all.gloveterms <- function (queries) 
{
  n <- length(queries)
  scores <- c(0)
  for(i in 1:n){
    query <- queries[i]
    wordvector = word_vectors[query, , drop = FALSE]
    cosine = sim2(x = word_vectors, y = wordvector, method = "cosine", norm = "l2")
    scores <- append(scores, max(cosine))
  }
  y <- as.integer(0)
  score <- sum(unlist(scores))/n
  feature[i] <- if (length(score)) score else y
}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of the content of word_vectors using dput?

Comment: My vocabulary consists of over 6000 words, so I couldn't fit all of them on here. Here's a sample: "above", "about", "sides", "backing", "fixtures", "star", "ri", 
"tight", "lamp", "patented", "mn", "saw", "delivery", "frost", 
"bowl", "common", "pet", "should", "locking", "bring", "mold", 
"tank", "ice", "reliable", "mounted", "within", "90", "onscreen", 
"enjoy", "watt", "homes", "elements", "contains", "cap", "designs"